# array of select - ngOptions

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using an ng-repeat to generate some data (username, login, role and actions). Each dropdown (role) has the same list of options.

Expected output : [image: Expected output]

Each row of data can have a different selected option (like the image) and a service call is made whenever a change is made to save the change.

My problem is that I can't choose different options for each row. Because they are all bound to the same ng-model, they all detect the change and all change to the new option.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="participant in model.participantData">
      <td>{{participant.DisplayName}}</td>
      <td>{{participant.UserLogin}}</td>
      <td>
        <label for="{{participant.ParticipantID}}" class="sr-only">
          Choose a role
        </label>
        <select id="{{participant.ParticipantID}}" data-ng-options="role.RoleID as role.RoleName for role in model.rolesData" data-ng-change="roleChanged(participant)" data-ng-model="model.chosenRole">
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-minus-circle clickable"</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Delete group member</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving same model , Give them model by `ng-repeat` instance

Like this

```
data-ng-model="participant.chosenRole"
```

Select will be

```
<select 
    id="{{participant.ParticipantID}}" 
    data-ng-options="role.RoleID as role.RoleName for role in model.rolesData" 
    data-ng-change="roleChanged(participant)" 
    data-ng-model="participant.chosenRole">
</select>
```

You can get selected value of each row from `model.participantData`

Comment: So adding a property to an array of objects populated from a service call. Is that something I should have picked up when I first started learning angular, or more of a time thing? This did not even cross my mind.

Comment: @Mathemats it's just tricks . you can't learn things like this from any book or documentation. this things comes from discussion during development.